# Count lines that contains a repeated pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed, filtering

I have a file (File.txt) that contains 10 lines which may contains a repeated patterns at a certain position (14-17)

```html
fsdf sfkljkl4565
fjjf lmlkfdm1235
fkljfgdfgdfg6583
eretjioijolj6933
ioj ijijsfoi4565
dgodiiopkpok6933
fsj opkjfiej4565
ihfzejijjijf4565
dfsdkfjlfeff1235
dijdijojijdz4565
```

The Desired Output is counting the lines that contains a pattern :

```html
 #occurences   pattern 
      5         4565
      2         1235
      1         6583
      2         6933
```

I have tried to filter the file

```
cat File.txt | cut -c14-17 | sort -n -K1,1-1,3 >> File_Filtered.txt
```

I need your help to add the first column (#occurences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a count of repeats, use `uniq -c`.  Thus, try:

```
 $ cut -c13-17 File.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr
      5 4565
      2 6933
      2 1235
      1 6583
```

The above was tested using Linux with GNU utilities.  (Judging by your sample code, you may be using different tools.)

#### Including a header

The following includes the header and uses `column -t` to assure that everything lines up nicely:

```
$ { echo '#occurences pattern'; cut -c13-17 File.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr; } | column -t
#occurences  pattern
5            4565
2            6933
2            1235
1            6583
```

Comment: Thanks man , it works fine , have you any idea how to add the header as well ?

Comment: @technopathe Yes.  I just added code that includes the headers.

Comment: Ooops , I tried it  but it doesn't work inside a script file. despite of being functional as a command line

Comment: @technopathe It should work in a script.  Please give me more details about how you are using it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{cnt[substr($0,13)]++} END{for (i in cnt) print cnt[i], i}' file
2 6933
1 6583
5 4565
2 1235
```

Comment: Awk is a Swiss army knife.  +1.